# Windows server 2022 ports required for vpn connections have been blocked by the firewall

Tags: vpn, l2tp

Im trying to enable VPN server(L2TP) inside windows 2022. everything goes as plan but in the end

the Remote Access Management Console Shows this error :

[image]

Ive also added rule for 1701 port in firewall like this (inbound and outbound) :

[image]

but still im getting the close port error.

if i do

> netstat -ab

in cmd i get this :

[image]

And finally if i run this in powershell :

> Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Domain,Public,Private -Enabled False

the problem will go away and all three checkmark will become green in operation status , but i got this error in client vpn :

[image]

Update : With suggestion Ive disabled the Default rule and add these one instead :

> New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "VPNTCP" -Direction inbound -Profile
> Any -Action Allow -LocalPort 1723,1701,443 -Protocol TCP

> New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "VPNUDP" -Direction inbound -Profile
> Any -Action Allow -LocalPort 500,4500,1701 -Protocol UDP

> New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "GRE" -Direction inbound -Protocol 47
> -Profile Any -Action Allow

Now it shows all green.

[image]

but still i cant connect to server from client and it shows this error :

> The l2tp connection attempt failed because the security layer
> encountered a processing error during initial negotiations with the
> remote computer

Comment: Create your own firewall rule. Don't edit the existing rules.

Comment: @GregAskew ive didnt edit any rule, and used predefined rule in firewall. In picture ive just double click the rule to show that its enable. no modification at all. do u sugget i should use predefined one and build new one ?

Comment: What do you think

Comment: @GregAskew I think i should use predefined rule without any edit. ive followed this tutorial step by step :
https://www.snel.com/support/how-to-set-up-an-l2tp-ipsec-vpn-on-windows-server-2019/

Comment: Typically you should create your own rule. If there is something that isn't working, post the packet capture.

Comment: @GregAskew Thanks for suggestion now all 3flag of VPN connectiviy is green. Ive updated my question with suggestion and login error.